# python how to implement a key stroke to leave menu and return to main menu

Tags: python

I would like if I could adapt my code so if any key except q the next two lines are shown but if the user presses q they are brought back to the main menu.  I can almost get the first half where any button will continue the scroll but dont know how to implement the q for quit.  Has any one any experience with something like this and can advise how to get the quit part to work?  This is my code so far

```
    sql = ('Select * from table;')  
    cursor.execute(sql)  
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
        for row in data[i:i+2]:
            print(row["ID"],":",  row["name"], ":", row["age"]) 
        input("--Quit (q) --")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql = 'Select * from table;'
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()

for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
    for row in data[i:i+2]:
        print(row["ID"],":",  row["name"], ":", row["age"]) 
    if input("--Quit (q) --") == "q":
        break
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you.